# What is the far most bottom part of a layout called and how do I change its color?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

There is a white part at the bottom of my layout. [image]

I guess this is the `parent`of the layout. How do I access it and change its color so that it's not white. I don't want to change the constraints as they are perfect for all the other times when the text is larger. The white just shows when there is little text.

If changing the constraints is the only way to solve this, then here is the full `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"


tools:context="com.nollvision.slothmode.nollvision.Detail1Activity">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail1_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"

        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/detail_text_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/backgroundTextView"

        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon1white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail1_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

        android:text="HEADER"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/backgroundTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subHeader"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail1_header" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subHeader" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"

        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/backgroundTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `ScrollView` XML add:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

This will use fill that white space at the bottom.

See [`fillViewPort`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport).

> Defines whether the scrollview should stretch its content to fill the viewport.